# Jquery resizable is not working properly with child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

for some reason resizable for the child is not working .

```
<div class="parent"><img class="child"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="child"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="child"></div>
```

When I tried `$(".parent").resizable( {alsoResize: ".child"});`then resizing is happen but it resize all images instead of corresponding image .

When i tried

```
$(".parent").resizable({ alsoResize: $(this).closest('.child') });
```

or

```
$(".parent").resizable({ alsoResize: $(this).find('.child') });
```

then only div is resizing , not the image inside. Why this happen?

Also  when i use `$(".child").resizable();` then `<div class="ui-wrapper" >` is coming and it become

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="ui-wrapper"><img class="child ui-resizable"></div>
</div>
```

but here what is the problem is img is not showing because display none is automatically coming , width and height of ui-wrapper class is not set or set 0 . please help to find out the problem .

Comment: `this` does not refer to the `.parent` element

Comment: so what i need to do ? and why it's not refer to the parent element ,since i started with selecting $(".parent") ? i think after the selection this refer to parent element

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your selector is incorrect; you're missing the `.` prefix. Secondly `this` does not refer to the `.parent` element, it refers to the scope the event handler is being created in. To fix this you can loop through the `.parent` elements and attach the events to them individually. Try this:

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    $(this).resizable({ 
        alsoResize: $(this).find('.child')
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no semicolon needed after  alsoResize: $(this).find('.child') .

Comment: thank you friend . Could you please write the reason for why we use each function ? . previously i write code without each function that time also   div resize is working .

Comment: It's because the logic you have depends on knowing the `.child` element of the current `.parent`. To do that your code has to run under the scope of each `.parent` element, which is why the `each()` is required here.